# Are there any simple models for wildfire hazard mapping with ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am interested in producing a simple fire hazard/severity map via ModelBuilder from commonly available datasets (e.g. DEM, NDVI, slope, aspect, land use/cover, etc).  Are there any resources or examples of simple models used to produce maps such as the example below?  Specifically, I am looking for a model that I can construct within about 10-15 minutes during a presentation to produce an interesting graphic.

[image]

Comment: For demonstration purposes, it will be difficult to construct a useful (and realistic) model in just 10-15 minutes.  Instead of trying to add every component into your model for the presentation, try creating a number of small sub-models which can contain the "details" of your analysis.  During your presentation, you can then 1) open each sub-model & show the processes going on, 2) drag the sub-model onto your "master" model, and 3) repeat steps 1 & 2 for each remaining sub-model.  This will be ensure you don't miss a step, and demonstrate the power of ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be such a model described in detail **[here](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0700/files/firemodel.pdf)**.  It uses the old ArcView 3 architecture but it looks like it could be adapted to ArcGIS 10.1.  Constructing it in 10-15 minutes would be a challenge so you may want to drop out some of its "less critical" input datasets.

Comment: Thanks, great link.  This link helped a great deal for putting together a simple fire risk model for a presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the example for a suitability-analysis shown in the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension tutorial and modify it using your criteria for wildfire risk. What you describe is in the end a "suitability analysis" for wildfires.

You can find the Tutorial [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exercise_3_Finding_a_site_for_a_new_school/00nt00000008000000/):

The model should be constructable in 10-15 minutes if you have your criteria preprocessed. The most important tools are "Reclassify" and "Weighted Overlay".

[image: Reclassify Tool]

[image: Weighted Overlay Tool]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depend on your purpos. first you should choose your method.for example u can use ahp,topsis,... methods if you want to rate your parameters or use fuzzy method or weithed overlay to overlay the layers and then create model using model builder and python scripting.